# Unable to boot Ubuntu

Tags: netbook, ubuntu-10.10, ubuntu-11.04, intel-atom, fsck

I used a live CD to install Ubuntu 10.10 on my HP Netbook (Mini Atom 1GHz CPU). I booted it up and then upgraded it to 11.04 Natty Narwhal. From the below I assume it got hacked, so how do I securely boot my laptop?

```
fsck util-linux-ng 2.17.2
fsck from util-linux-ng 2,17.2
/dev/sda5/: clean, 161364/7331840 files, 1234296/29314560 blocks
found 280698880 bytes used err is 0
total csum bytes : 269584
total tree byte:4644864
total fs tree bytes:3477504
btree space waste bytes:877726
file data ocks allocacated:2134724608
referenced:244753536
btrfs v0.19
Init :unreadaheda-other main process terminated with status 4

 *starting network manager
skipping profile in /etc/apparmor/.d/disable: usr:.bin.firefox
```

Comment: What specifically from the pasted text tells you that it was hacked?  From the looks of it you retyped the text shown; is that accurate, or are the apparent typos the reason for your hacking assertion?  Also, what filesystem type was /dev/sda5?  Next, how much time passed between the 10.10 install and the 11.04 upgrade?  Finally, why is booting with the live CD insufficiently secure?